# JDBC when does Auto-Commit commit

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-server-2012

I am working on reducing deadlocks and it was pointed out to me that I should not use multiple queries with one connection because the transaction may not be committed and open, causing deadlocks. So in pseudo code, something like this:

```
try(Connection con = datasource.getConnection()) 
    {
        PreparedStatement stm1 = con.prepareStatement(getSQL());
        stm1.setString(1, owner);
        stm1.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        stm1.setInt(3, count);

        int updateCount = stm1.executeUpdate();
        stm1.close();


        PreparedStatement stm2 = con.prepareStatement(getSQL2());
        stm2.setString(1, owner);
        ResultSet rs = stm2.executeQuery();

        List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            results.add(create(rs));
        }

        return results;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to claim message",e);
    }
```

When does stm1 commit the transaction when auto-commit is set to true?

Is it good practise to reuse a connection like that or should both statements use separate connections instead?

Comment: The first statement is committed immediately when `stm1.executeUpdate();` is called.

Comment: i would strive to reuse connections as opening a connection has overhead. you could also just do one call if you concat sql1 and sql2.

Comment: Sql 1 is an update, while 2 is a select depending on that update. Sql1 causes a deadlock with a different update, which is why I was wondering if sql2 holds a transaction open for too long causing that deadlock. In any case, they can't be expressed in 1 query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions like these can usually be answered by reading the [JDBC specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/index.html). JDBC 4.2 section 10.1 *Transaction Boundaries and Auto-commit* says:

> When to start a new transaction is a decision made implicitly by
>   either the JDBC driver or the underlying data source. Although some
>   data sources implement an explicit “begin transaction” statement,
>   there is no JDBC API to do so. Typically, a new transaction is started
>   when the current SQL statement requires one and there is no
>   transaction already in place. Whether or not a given SQL statement
>   requires a transaction is also specified by SQL:2003.
>
> The `Connection` attribute *auto-commit* specifies when to end
>   transactions. Enabling auto-commit causes a transaction commit after
>   each  individual SQL statement as soon as that statement is complete.
>   The point at which a statement is considered to be “complete” depends
>   on the type of SQL statement as well as what the application does
>   after executing it:
>
> - For Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements such as Insert, Update, Delete, and DDL statements, the statement is complete as soon
>     as it has finished executing.
> - For `Select` statements, the statement is complete when the associated result set is closed.
> - For `CallableStatement` objects or for statements that return multiple results, the statement is complete when all of the associated
>     result sets have been closed, and all update counts and output
>     parameters have been retrieved.

In your code a transaction is committed as part of `stm1.executeUpdate()` (this transaction might have been started on prepare, or on execute). A new transaction is started at prepare or execute of `stmt2`, but as you don't close `stmt2` or `rs`, the connection close will trigger the commit.

As to whether you should reuse connections and statements: it depends on context and your code. For a specific unit of work you use a single connection. If you want further reuse of connections you should use a connection pool. Reusing statements should only be done when it makes sense to do so (otherwise your code might get complicated with resource leaks as a consequence), and again there are connection pools that provide built-in statement pooling that reduces this complexity for you.

Statements like *"[..] should not use multiple queries with one connection because the transaction may not be committed and open, causing deadlocks."* are usually incorrect and would lead to badly performing applications if applied. It might apply to misbehaving drivers that don't properly follow the auto-commit rules above, or maybe in situations were the connection is much longer lived and you don't properly finish a statement (like in the case of `stmt2`). That said, it is usually better to disable auto-commit and explicitly commit or rollback when you are done.

Your code could be improved by using *try-with-resources* for the statements and result sets as well, as this ensures result set and statement are closed as soon as possible, even when exceptions occur:

```
try (Connection con = datasource.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement stm1 = con.prepareStatement(getSQL())) {
        stm1.setString(1, owner);
        stm1.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        stm1.setInt(3, count);

        int updateCount = stm1.executeUpdate();
    }

    try (PreparedStatement stm2 = con.prepareStatement(getSQL2())) {
        stm2.setString(1, owner);
        try (ResultSet rs = stm2.executeQuery()) {

            List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
            while(rs.next()) {
                results.add(create(rs));
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to claim message", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When auto-commit mode is disabled, no SQL statements are committed until you call the method commit explicitly. All statements executed after the previous call to the method commit are included in the current transaction and committed together as a unit.

As you set auto-commit true, it is committed immediate in data base.

It good practice to reuse a connection.This is perfectly safe as long as the same connection is not is use by two threads at the same time